# How to extract values between 2 known strings

Tags: regex, xml, search, sed, extract

I have some huge files containing mixed binary and xml data. I want to extract all values between 2 XML tags that have multiple occurrences in the file. Pattern would be as following: `<C99><F1>050</F1><F2>random value</F2></C99>` . Portions of XML data are not formatted, everything is in a single line.

I need all values between `<F1>` and `</F1>` from `<C99>` where value is between range 050 and 999(`<F1>` exists under other fields as well but I need only values of F1 from C99). I need to count them, to see how many C99 have F1 with values between 050 and 999.

I want a hint how I could easily reach and extract that values (using cat and grep? or sed?). Sorting and counting is easy to do it once values are exported in a file.

My temporary solution:

After removing all binary data from the file, I can run the following command:

```
cat filename | grep -o "<C99><F1>......." > file.txt
```

This will export first 12 characters from all strings starting with `<C99><F1>.`

```
<C99><F1>001
<C99><F1>056
<C99><F1>123
<C99><F1>445
```

.....

Once exported in a text file, I replace `<C99><F1>` with nothing and then I sort and count remaining values.

Thank you!

Comment: This probably will bring too many downvotes, unless you show at least some effort and attempts to solve your own problem

Comment: It won't work using an XML Parse since some data in binary format which I don't need it anyway.

Comment: I was embarrassed to post my solution, but you can see it now.

Answer (score 2):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xml sel -t -v '//C99/F1[. >= 50 and . <= 999]' -nl data.xml | wc -l
```

Not much of a hint there, sorry.

Comment: Very nice tool, didn't know it